# Where can I get data on the number of hours worked by Americans?

Tags: data-request, usa, population

I don't necessarily need microdata on the number of hours worked, but I would like to see some data on the percentile scale. I can't seem to find anything except for averages, which are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've already found averages at [Current Employment Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/ces/#tables), [FactFinder](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/index.xhtml), or the [American Time-Use Survey](https://www.bls.gov/tus/). I don't see any percentiles there.

I don't know of any ready-made tables from BLS or Census that include percentiles for hours worked, so unfortunately you will probably need to create your own tabulation using microdata from [CPS PUMS](https://thedataweb.rm.census.gov/ftp/cps_ftp.html) or [ACS PUMS](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/data/pums.html). Be aware that this does require significant expertise in working with weighted survey data and knowing which records to filter out by labor force status etc.